# Object creation with tuple unpacking within a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm curious if I can unpack a tuple returned from a function and use the unpacked values to create an Object, all within a list comprehension.

The code I hope to use looks like:

```
data = [
    Availability(
        user=random.randrange(100),
        start_time, end_time=generateTimes(),
    )
    for x in range(10000)
]
```

The above code gives me the error `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`. I'd prefer to use list comprehension over a traditional for loop if possible.

Comment: I updated the post to clarify what error occurs.

Comment: "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument" has nothing to do with being in a list comprehension, you need to pass all positional arguments before keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `start_time, end_time=generateTimes()`

This will not unpack the return value. This will instead pass the (probably undefined) variable `start_time` as a positional argument (that's why you get the `SyntaxError`), and the two return values from `generateTimes()` as a keyword argument. It's not possible like you did it, the only hope you have is as following:
If you have the `Availability` constructor defined like this:

```py
    def __init__(self, user=0, start_time=0, end_time=1)
```

You can omit the keywords and pass the arguments like positional ones.

```py
Availability(
        random.randrange(100),
        *generateTimes()
)
```

But if your Availability class constructor has more than these three keyword arguments this will most likely not work. Then, you have to call the function twice like this:

```py
Availability(
        random.randrange(100),
        start_time=generateTimes()[0],
        end_time=generateTimes[1]
)
```

EDIT
I found another solution (untested though) using `map()`:

```py
data = [
    Availability(
        user=random.randrange(100),
        start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time
    )
    for start_time, end_time in map(lambda _: generateTimes(), range(10000))
]
```

Comment: Thank you. 
    Availability(
        random.randrange(100),
        *generateTimes()
    )
Ended up solving this issue.

Comment: @Bonteq then please accept the answer using the grey checkmark on the left of it

Comment: So far as I can tell, it does.

Comment: @Bonteq hey look at my answer again, I found a even better solution !

Comment: The new solution gives me the error `TypeError: generateTimes() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right, thanks !